# Eclipse Juno/Ubuntu 14.04 Server

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, ubuntu

I am using **"Java All-in-One for Dummies"** by Doug Lowe to try to learn Java.  It is a fantastic book and I have learned a lot from it, but considering Lowe was using Windows and Notepad to write his code and I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Eclipse Juno, there have been some inconsistencies.  I'm afraid one of those may be using Sockets and ServerSockets.  I am using his BartServer example but when I run it in Eclipse, it merely prints the `System.out.println()` information to the terminal, but stops once it hits the code just `out.println()`. I apologize, I know this isn't very descriptive, but I don't want to post his code without permission.  If pictures are needed of my terminal, I'd be happy to provide those.  I guess what I'm asking is there some special way Eclipse has to be run in order to connect to servers, similar to how you have to add command line arguments separately? Or am I just making a mistake when running this program?

I've decided to post the code to help out, so I will remove this when I'm done.

```
public class BartServer {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    int port = 5555;

    BartQuote bart = new BartQuote();

    try
    {
        System.out.println("BartServer 1.0");
        System.out.println("Listening on port " + port);
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket();
        ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        Socket s;
        s = ss.accept();

        String client;
        client = s.getInetAddress().toString();
        System.out.println("Connected to" + client);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        PrintWriter out;
        out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);

        out.println("Welcome to BartServer 1.0");
        out.println("Enter GET to get a quote or BYE to exit.");

        while(true)
        {
            String input = in.nextLine();
            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("BYE"))
                break;
            else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("GET"))
            {
                out.println(bart.getQuote());
                System.out.println("Serving " + client);
            }
            else
                out.println("Huh?");
        }
        out.println("So long, suckers!");
        s.close();
        System.out.println("Closed connection to " + client);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, try to reduce your code to the minimum to understand it's flow, it's sense and still containing the error. Maybe its just an include or something? Which java version is installed (java -version) and which eclipse package did you load (e.g. Eclipse IDE for Java Developers)?

Comment: Eclipse generally won't stop on a  System.out.println() so there's something else going on. Any error messages? Have you tried the same code in a text editor & command line as per book? Also in my 10 years Java I've never once programmed Sockets!

Comment: maybe it keeps hitting the exit condition for some reason

Comment: I have tried running this through the command-line and gedit and it still stops there.  I think it's that the program is sending the information to port 5555 and I don't know how to "listen" to that port, could somebody explain how to do that with eclipse?

Comment: why would eclipse need to listen to a port? the program needs to listen to to port which would be the reader side of the socket. if you dont have a reader for the socket then a lot is explained...also sockets aren't blocking (sit and wait) they are loop forever until a condition is met or read once and exit.

Comment: @jgr208 I'm afraid I don't understanding what I'm doing wrong then.  I thought the information being sent to port 5555 would also show up in my terminal, is that not correct?  I'm afraid I don't fully understand ports or Sockets very well

Comment: from my understanding of sockets and someone can correct me if i am wrong, you have a reader listening to a port and a writer writing to a port. think of the port as a house address for UPS. You order a package and put your address in then wait for the package then the package gets there and you open it. So the port is like the house number where it serves as the this is where i am so I don't read someone else's information. There is a client side and a server side to a socket.

Comment: http://www.cs.uic.edu/~troy/spring05/cs450/sockets/socket.html has some examples to look at

Comment: Thank you guys, I think I'm starting to understand.  I guess the part that I'm confused about is how do I see what's happening in the port?  Like is there a problem with this code stopping it from working?  Or is the issue more than I don't know where to read and write information through the port while the program's running?  And also, thank you guys so much for your help :)